# When is the optimal time to use the HTTP method PATCH instead of PUT?

Tags: rest, http, put

Although `PUT` & `PATCH` are used for same purpose that is for updating resource. But when should i use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`? And same goes for vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PUT` when the body you're sending is the complete resource to create or overwrite — that is, basically the same thing that you would `GET` back at the same address. Use `PATCH` if the body is a representation of how to *change* an existing resource.

Comment: Can you please explain it in more details by giving a real world scenario? It'll be good for me to understand more better way if you provide an example.

Comment: @RashedRahat maybe you can make an effort explaining what you don't understand about this answer. I found it quite clear, but then, I already knew of the concept. Can you explain how this does not make sense?

Answer (score 2):

> when should i use PATCH instead of PUT?

Use patch when the patch document is much smaller than the complete representation, and you don't care about the benefits of idempotent messaging.

Both PATCH and PUT have remote authoring semantics, which is to say that the requests mean "please make your copy of the target resource match my copy".  In the case of PUT, we are sending a complete copy of the new representation; in the case of PATCH, we are sending a patch document -- which is to say a representation of the changes that we have made.

PUT is [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2); general purpose components know that no damage will occur if the server happens to receive two copies of the message.  That means, among other things, if we are sending messages on unreliable transport, a client can react to a lost response by resending the request *without needing any additional permissions*.

PATCH is *not* idempotent; the guarantees it makes are very similar to those of POST.  Therefore, a general purpose component will NOT know that it is safe to retry a request if the response is lost.

(There are some patch document formats that support idempotent handling -- [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6) is one example.  But it isn't *generally* true, and that knowledge isn't available in a "readily standardizable form" that general purpose clients can discover.)